# Can epoll_wait() > 1 with only 1 socket and 1 event -- EPOLLIN?

Tags: c++, c, linux, epollet

Let's say I epoll_create1() and only interest in EPOLLIN | EPOLLET for 1 socket.

Is it possible that I will get epoll_wait() > 1 (assuming timeout=-1) for that socket and the event is EPOLLIN?

Or will epoll_wait() return 1 even there are multiple packets (let's say spread over few sec that I pause the program on purpose in the epoll_wait loop)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With edge-triggered mode you have to be particularly careful to drain the file descriptor for each event type that fired, or you won't see future events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`epoll_wait` returns the number of *events*, which according to the documentation equals the "number of file descriptors ready for I/O". So you cannot get more events than the number of file descriptors you have registered.

Comment: If the socket has some data ready and then gets disconnected, epoll_wait() will first return 1 with event=EPOLLIN and then the next epoll_wait() will return 1 with event=EPOLLRDHUP? In other words, epoll_wait() won't return 2 for the same file descriptor but 2 different events?

Comment: @Hei: Good question. Maybe [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6437879/596781). The manual says that events are combined, so perhaps you should check for readability as well as for hup.

Answer (score 1):

According to these docs for [`epoll_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) it should return the number of fd's that are "ready". If you only pass in one fd, then you should not get more than 1 back - that would certainly be a bug in the `epoll_wait` implementation, and it's been around for a while, so I expect it's fairly well tested (unless you are working on a completely new architecture or a beta-version of a C library or some such).

Also, timeout = 0, not -1.

Comment: Thanks. timeout=-1 means blocking and timeout=0 means non-blocking tho :)