# Why do we need EPOLLRDHUP when EPOLLHUP seems enough?

Tags: c, linux, networking, api-design, epoll

According to the linux [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html),

> **EPOLLHUP**
>
> When reading from a channel such as a pipe or a stream socket, 
>   this event merely indicates that the peer closed its end of the channel.
>
> **EPOLLRDHUP**
>
> Stream socket peer closed connection, or shut down writing half of connection.

I can hardly tell any difference between `EPOLLHUP` and `EPOLLRDHUP`.

To me, whenever `EPOLLRDHUP` is used `EPOLLHUP` can be used instead with the same semantics.

Am I right? If not, any explanations?

Comment: EPOLLHUP means you can't write, EPOLLRDHUP (and read()==0) means you can't read. https://medium.com/where-the-flamingcow-roams/down-the-epoll-rabbit-hole-5c0447cb6329

Comment: No. EPOLLHUP means you half-close the socket and the peer half-closes the socket too. (So you can't either read or write) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976152/tcp-when-is-epollhup-generated.

Comment: Here is nice explanation for these two flags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438173/7888101

Comment: They mean slightly different things and require different handling.  Read the man page for shutdown (2)

Answer (score 0):

- `EPOLLHUP` means that the peer closed their end of the connection. **Writing to the connection is closed**, and after any (possible) readable data is consumed, reading from the connection is closed, too.
- `EPOLLRDHUP` only means that the peer closed their connection, or only half of their connection. If it's only halfway closed, the stream socket turns into a one-way, write-only connection. **Writing to the connection may still be open**, but after any (possible) readable data is consumed, reading from the connection is closed.

This may be done if the peer calls `shutdown()` on their socket descriptor, disallowing itself from writing data:

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>

int sockfd = /* ... */;
shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR);
```

Comment: Not possible. The localhost cannot detect any difference between the peer closing the socket and shutting it down for output.

Comment: @user207421 I don't understand. Where did I say that localhost can tell the difference? Shut down for output in the perspective of the peer, or localhost?